# How to analyze the heap dump file generated by JMeter

Tags: jmeter

While I am running my test both from GUI and non-GUI, observing out of memory error and JMeter generate e HPROF file as the dump. How is analyze this file ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically a heap dump is a snapshot of the memory of a Java™ process.

Reference: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3KLZ/com.ibm.java.diagnostics.memory.analyzer.doc/heapdump.html

Reference: https://dzone.com/articles/java-heap-dump-analyzer-1

you can use Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT) for Heap Analysis

Reference : https://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Answer (score 0):

And what do you expect to see in this file? When [OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) exception occurs it tells you what exactly went wrong, the most common reasons are in:

- **Java heap space** - in this case just increase the JVM Heap allocated to JMeter, the relevant line for jmeter.bat file is [this one](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/jmeter.bat#L151)

  ```
  set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
  ```

  amend this `Xmx` which sets the maximum heap boundary as needed by your test scenario
- **GC Overhead limit exceeded**  - indicates that the JVM is doing [garbage collection](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) > 90% of time, it indicates that there are too many new objects in Heap (or its size is too small)
- **Requested array size exceeds VM limit** - when there is an object which doesn't fit into Heap
- **Metaspace** - [the same line in jmeter.bat file](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/jmeter.bat#L151), i.e. if you're actively use JSR223 Test Elements each occurrence creates a class and the number of loaded classes doesn't fit into the metaspace
- **request size bytes for reason. Out of swap space?** - self explanatory
  -etc.

So you need to read the message (and .hprof file is a normal text file, you can open it with your favourite text editor will contain some more information), understand the reason and amend your JMeter configuration to eliminate this reason.

More information: [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)